# Formula to center a rectangle on paper with rotation

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am trying to rotate a rectangle on a paper in below way

```
  var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('element'), 400, 400);
  paper.rect(1, 200, 200, 200).animate({transform:"r-45,200,200"}, 2000);
```

But this is not [complete](http://jsfiddle.net/jhG7S/). Is there any kind of algorithm to center the rectangle inside paper. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to rotate also in the center of the rectangle? You can do so like this:

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('element'), 400, 400);
paper.rect(100, 100, 200, 200).animate({transform:"r-360,200, 200"}, 20000);
```

I updated [the example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhG7S/1/), I changed your rotation and time but you can do what you like with those.